# Problems pertaining to compilation of C++ application in g++ (probable cause #ifndef)

Tags: c++, g++, compilation

I am trying to build a Linked list application using C++ programming language & features such as inheritance etc.

I have split the interface & implementation in different files but not able to compile.

Below are the list of files

Interface files :- node.h , abstractList.h , singleLinkedList.h

Implementation files: singleLinkedList.cpp

node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <iostream>

struct nodeType {
        int data;
        struct nodeType *next;
}listNode;


#endif
```

abstractList.h

```
#ifndef ABSTRACT_LIST_H
#define ABSTRACT_LIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
#include "singleLinkedList.h"

class abstractList {
        public:
        virtual ~abstractList();
        virtual bool isEmpty(Node* ) = 0;
        virtual int get(const int&) = 0;
        virtual int indexOf(const int& ) = 0;
        virtual Node insert(const int& , const int& ) = 0;
        virtual void delete(const int& ) = 0;
};

#endif
```

singleLinkedList.h

```
#ifndef SINGLE_LIST_H
#define SINGLE_LIST_H

#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
#include "abstractList.h"

class singleLinkedList : public abstractList {

        public:

        singleLinkedList();
        ~singleLinkedList();
        Node populateList( );

        private:

        void checkIndex();
        int data;
        Node head;
};

#endif
```

So far i have just coded the populateList() function in the implentation file, here goes the implementation file.

singleLinkedList.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"
#include "singleLinkedList.h"
#include "abstractList.h"


    Node singleLinkedList :: populateList()
    {
            Node temp;
            int data;
            temp = head;
            char ch;
            std::cout<<"Enter Data? (y/n) " << std::endl;
            std::cin>>ch;

            while(ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y')
            {
                    std::cout<<"Enter the data that you would like to store.\n"<<std::endl;
                    std::cin>>data;
                    temp = new Node();
                    temp->data = data;
                    temp->next = head;
                    head = temp;
                    std::cout<<"Enter more data?"<<std::endl;
                    std::cin>>"\n">>ch;
            }

            return temp;
    }
```

When i give g++ -c singleLinkedList.cpp , i am getting lot of errors. I am pretty sure i have done something stupid. Can anyone please pin point my error?

EDIT: Error Log With specfic issues.

```
struct nodeType {
int data;
struct nodeType *next;
}listNode;
```

virtual listNode *insert();

Is the above statement correct?

Thanks
Kelly

Comment: Maybe adding the actual error messages could prove helpful.

Comment: Very good. Now, there's a lot of error messages; why don't you start solving them? The first one should be easy: `abstractList.h:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘delete’` - `delete` is a keyword, you cannot use it as a method name. Either change the name of the method, or implement operator delete instead. Proceed with the rest of the error messages and tell us which one exactly gets you stuck.

Comment: Changed delete to Delete(). 
The typedef in node.h seems to give the trouble

typedef struct tag {
       .....
}list

typedef list *Node;
Node populateList()

In Implementation file.
Node ClassName :: populateList()

I am not getting whats wrong here? :(

Comment: Actually, I'm voting to close on this one. There is more than one problem here, the OP should at least make an effort to solve as many of them as possible and then post individual informed questions on each problem that remains.

Comment: @tdammers , i am putting all my efforts. As a result most of the errors are reduced..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` is a keyword in C++, you can't use it as a method name. You need to use a different name here:

```
class abstractList {
        public:
        //...
        virtual void delete(const int& ) = 0;
        //-----------^^^^^^ rename this.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your typedef:

```
typedef listNode *Node;
```

means that all instances of `Node` will essentially replaced by `listnode*`

```
  temp = new Node();
```

actually reads

```
  temp = new listnode*();
```

But `new Foo()` would return a Foo* (because new returns a pointer to memory allocated for an object), meaning that `new listnode*()` would return a `listnode**`. `temp` being a `listnode*` has no Idea what a `listnode**` is and complains.

what you want to do is:

```
 Node temp = new listnode();
```

or forget the typedef altogether:

```
 listnode* temp = new listnode();
```

Comment: Thanks Dave for the clear explanation. I am now without typedefs.

However , i am getting few errors(although much less)

I have my node as   struct nodeType { ,,... }listNode;

virtual listNode *fooo(listNode *) ; would  anything like this be wrong?